# What is [AR] for gpg / gnupg authentication keys?

Tags: gpg

I used Dr Duh's yubikey setup about 20 days ago with no issue.  I ran through it again last night on an M1 Mac with Brew and when we created the expiring authentication key, the keylist shows [AR] for the key where it would normally show just [A] for authentication. I have consulted the man pages on gnu.org and while I can see the other codes (E,S,A) - I see no definition for R.  What is R?

This is something like what I see on the list step (copied from Dr Duh's guide and altered to add the R):

```
$ gpg -K
/tmp.FLZC0xcM/pubring.kbx
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
sec   rsa4096/0xFF3E7D88647EBCDB 2017-10-09 [C]
      Key fingerprint = 011C E16B D45B 27A5 5BA8  776D FF3E 7D88 647E BCDB
uid                            Dr Duh <doc@duh.to>
ssb   rsa4096/0xBECFA3C1AE191D15 2017-10-09 [S] [expires: 2018-10-09]
ssb   rsa4096/0x5912A795E90DD2CF 2017-10-09 [E] [expires: 2018-10-09]
ssb   rsa4096/0x3F29127E79649A3D 2017-10-09 [AR] [expires: 2018-10-09]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these letters signify the *capabilities*. Reading https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/blob/master/doc/DETAILS#field-12---key-capabilities I think the `R` means "restricted encryption".

With regard to the case difference: "...in addition to these letters, the primary key has uppercase versions of the letters to denote the usable capabilities of the entire key...".

Comment: I see restricted encryption mentioned in the list archives:
https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2023-May.txt

So I believe you are correct.  Should I ask a different question as to what this flag means?

Comment: Well, your question was what the `R` represents. By going through the source code and the DETAILS doc I gave you the answer. Not sure what "restricted encryption" means exactly... maybe someone else can help you out with that.

Comment: I will give you the answer check and either ask on the mailing list or ask another question